# view model list return null object

Tags: list, exception, model-view-controller, null, viewmodel

view code:

```
@using HRHPMVS.Models
@model HRHPMVS.ViewModel.NationalityVM
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "list";
    //Layout = "~/Views/Shared/OrangeHR.cshtml";
    Layout = null;
}
<h1>Details</h1>
<div>

    <h1>Details</h1>
    <div>
@if (Model.NationalitiesList != null)
{

      foreach (var item in Model.NationalitiesList)
      {
         @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Code) 

      }
}

    </div>
</div>
```

controller code:

```
public ActionResult list()
{
    ModelState.Clear();
    NationRepObj.list();
    return View();
}
```

model:

```
namespace HRHPMVS.Models
{
    public class Nationality
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is Requirde")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "please: Use letters only ")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
         [Display(Name = "Code")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Code is Requirde")]
        [RegularExpression(@"[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+", ErrorMessage = "{0} must be a Number.")]
        [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please: enter valid integer Number")]
        public int Code { get; set; }
        public Nullable<short> IsActive { get; set; }
        // ...
    }
}
```

viewmodel:

```
namespace HRHPMVS.ViewModel
{
    public class NationalityVM
    {
        public Nationality Nationality { get; set; }
        public List<Nationality> NationalitiesList { get; set; }
        // ...
    }
}
```

viewmodellist:

```
namespace HRHPMVS.ViewModel
{
    public class NationalityVMList
    {
      public List<NationalityVM> Nationalities {get;set;}
      // ...
    }
}
```

function :

```
public   void  list()
{
    List<Nationality> n = new List<Nationality>();
    Nationality nt = new Nationality { Code=1,Name="doodoo",ID=1,IsActive=1};
    NationalityVM vm = new NationalityVM ();
    List<NationalityVM> l1 = new List<NationalityVM>();
   // foreach(var itm in nt)
    n.Add(nt);
    if (vm.NationalitiesList == null)
    {
        vm.NationalitiesList = new List<Nationality>();
        vm.NationalitiesList.Add(nt);

    }
}
```

I am trying to view detailed nationality in a view. I want to view it from listviewmodel but I failed. I made the viewmodel list point to view model and view model point to model but when I am trying to add nationality to list in return null value with error `Null reference exception wasn't handled in user code`.

I want to display nationality detail from viewmodel list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with this code that it is hard to know what you are trying to achieve.

You have a class dubbed 'viewmodellist' called NationalityVMList. I don't believe this has a purpose. Maybe delete it.

Your view expects a model of type NationalityVM but your controller action passes nothing to it.

Your 'function' creates a list along with several unused variables and returns nothing.

Change your controller so it passes a model to the view:

```
public ActionResult list()
{
    NationalityVM model = NationRepObj.GetNationalityVM();
    ModelState.Clear();
    return View(model);
}
```

Change your function to:

```
public NationalityVM GetNationalityVM()
{
    NationalityVM vm = new NationalityVM();
    Nationality nt = new Nationality { Code=1,Name="doodoo",ID=1,IsActive=1};
    vm.NationalitiesList = new List<Nationality>();
    vm.Add(nt);
    return vm;
}
```

Hopefully this will get something working.

Comment: thx my missing line was in controller :   NationalityVM model = NationRepObj.GetNationalityVM(); return View(model)  i was trying to figure out way to bind data from nested model , i was thinking if i separate viewmodel into 2 sub viewmodel one for master data  and another  one for details

Comment: Glad it worked. Please mark as answer if this has solved your issue.